# Facebook like button not appearing on certain browsers

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I have a facebook like button on my [website](http://www.leonhowmancars.co.uk) (it's in the right side of the menu bar).  The URL it is pointing to is actually back to my facebook page at [www.facebook.com/leonhowmancars](http://www.facebook.com/leonhowmancars).

It works fine on some browsers (Chrome, IE11 Modern UI on Windows 8.1, Stock Android Browser on my HTC Phone), but on other browsers (Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE11 Desktop on Windows 8.1, IE10 on Win7, Chrome on my HTC Phone, iPad) it just doesn't display the facebook like buttons.  There are no errors, it just isn't rendered.

At first I thought maybe it was the code in my webpage at fault (even though I copy pasted it directly from the facebook developers page), but then I found that if I go to the [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) page and enter the URL to like as "http://www.facebook.com/leonhowmancars" it doesn't render there in Firefox, Safari, Opera etc either!   If I change the URL to like to one of my other facebook pages (eg: "http://www.facebook.com/thepistolsuk") it's fine.  So that leads me to believe the problem is not with the code in my webpage.

Any suggestions on what's at fault here??

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/leonhowmancars is redirected to facebook homepage for me, is your page all ight?

Comment: Hmmm that's odd, the page is certainly published.  I can't see any other settings that would be restricting the page from being displayed.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, you have got me on the trail now.  It's not specific browsers that are the problem.  I can't see the page either unless I am logged into facebook, so looks like some sort of permissions problem on the page itself.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help from Ivan allowed me to track down the cause.  If I was not logged into facebook, going to http://www.facebook.com/leonhowmancars just redirected to the facebook home page rather than the actual page itself.

I found that if I removed the country restriction (I had the page setup to ONLY display to the United Kingdom) that fixed my problem.